# Web View not returning a correct value

Tags: javascript, android-webview

With version 2.3.3 from web view i am getting result string as 1364311909

But with the same 4.0 or above i am getting 1.36431e+09 a string value in different format

The Value is passing from a javascript to a webview using Web View Android Frame Work

The Webview Used With JavaScript enable   :

```
myWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
                        System.out.println("default encoding state is...."+myWebView.getSettings().getDefaultTextEncodingName());
                        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

                        myWebView.loadUrl("the Url");
```

JavaScript Code for retrieving the value is

```
public void changeIntent(final String updateId) {


        showToast(updateId);


         //* addToUpdatesId(updateId);
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // your code here
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,XXX.class);



                String allId= updateId;
                Global.setUpdateId(updateId);




                intent.putExtra(UPDATESID, allId);

                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        };

        runOnUiThread(runnable); 


    }
```

How to solve this issue. Plz let me know

Comment: 1. both values are the same. its the same number. you would get the same amount of pieces of cake. 2. What about some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have solved it

Java Script Always take High Precision Value and it well add power of exponential at the end of the String

To make this solve Append a Empty String with the Original String That you are passing 
and return a string.
like 
String s= Original string+"";
return s;

Cheers......!!!!!!!!!!!